# Appending element to a list resets the scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple `ul` where I append a bunch of new li elements using jquery. This works well in the most cases but sometimes the scroll position of the list is reset back to 0, right after appending the new `li`s. Anyone know why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you use *something* like this code, yeah it happens:

```
<a href="#" id="append">Append</a>
```

And in jQuery, you *might* have given the code this way:

```
$("#append").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>");
});
```

If that is the case, you need to give a `return false;` to the function.

```
$("#append").click(function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>");
    return false;
});
```

#### Please give more details if this is not what you are looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the following to styles are  responsible for the behavior:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```